# spring boot API failure retrigger mechanism

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, error-handling

I am working on designing a process where in case of any rest api failure, the payload and other request details are stored in a table and a process resubmits the request to the API.
This is a generic table where failure on any registered API (another table) can be retriggered.
The high level table structure is as below:
*Process table*- process name, description, scheduled time(cron expression), HTTP method type, API URL to invoke
*Failure table*- process name, payload/headers/path parameters, create time, success/failure

Dynamic scheduling per process will be performed as per the cron expression (available in table), and each job will pick all failures messages from the failure table and trigger the API.

I would like to get inputs on improving this design or any alternative design or any available library on similar lines which can be used instead of re-inventing the wheel.